# How to replace variable in Karate

Tags: karate

I need to replace a value inside the URL

```
test/lambda-migration/v1/quote'
```

The v1 needs to be parameterized to take different value, and these values will come from another feature file. My code looks kike this:

Feature file -1

Scenario Outline: Lambda API registration

Given url ApiAdminURL

```
json myReq = read('swagger-lambda.json')
```

And request `myReq`

When method post

Then status

```
def responsefromsubscriber = call read('Subscriber.feature') { InvokeStatus: '#(InvokeStatus)', version: '<version>' }

match responsefromsubscriber.InvokeStatus == 200

Examples: 
  | responseCode | version |
  |          200 | v1      |
```

Feature File - 2

Given url internalGateway

```
print 'Version: ' , version 

def LocalVersion = version

print 'LocalVersion: ' , LocalVersion
```

And path `'test/lambda-migration/#(LocalVersion)/quote'`

And header `Authorization = accessTokenforInvokation`

When method get

This is not replacing #(LocalVersion) to v1

Comment: Code into code tags. Better formatting, wording and drafting in general would be highly beneficial, since it is currently difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
And path 'test/lambda-migration/#(LocalVersion)/quote'
```

This is wrong. Please read this part of the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

Also note that [`path`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#url) supports a comma-delimited form:

Try:

```
And path 'test/lambda-migration', LocalVersion, 'quote'
```